# How to implement %% to split string like shell in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, split

I am new to ruby and I want to do the following action to remove last "_val3" in ruby:

```
$ val="val1_val2_val3"
$ echo ${val%_*}
val1_val2
```

I used to use echo ${val%_*} to get "val1_val2", but i do not how do this in ruby.
Also, how to get "val1"?
Is there a good way to do them?

Comment: ...and are you talking about `%` or `%%` in your shell parameter expansion?

Comment: Please explain (in words) what you want to do. Not everyone knows how parameter substitution works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single gsub to get your expected o/p,

```
a = "a-b_c_d"
# => "a-b_c_d"
a.gsub /_[a-z]*$/, ''
# => "a-b_c"
```

Or, you can use ruby split and join,

```
a.split("_")[0..-2].join("_")
# => "a-b_c"
```

Comment: how can i to remove all _* with gsub?

Comment: “Single `gsub`” in ruby is called `sub`.

Comment: @daixiang0: Just add a dot(.) before * cahr => a.gsub /_[a-z].*$/, ''

Answer (score 1):

Not a ruby expert but I'll get the ball rolling with a regular expression:

```
a.sub /_[^_]*$/, ''
```

Match an underscore followed by any number of non-underscores at the end of the string. Replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[`String#rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-rpartition) would probably work:

```
'a-b_c_d'.rpartition('_') #=> ["a-b_c", "_", "d"]
```

`rpartition` looks for the last `'_'` and returns an array containing the part before it, the separator itself and the part after it.